# How can I empty a bucket of stinky water under my sink?

Tags: kitchens, sink, smell

Well, the kitchen sink was leaking and a family member stuck a bucket under there and never told anybody. The problem is the pipes under the sink actually go into the bucket and it is full of water that smells HORRIBLE. I can't move the bucket without spilling horrible smelling water everywhere. I tried using a fast food cup to remove small amounts at a time but the fumes made me light headed and I got some on my hand.

Any other ideas at all? My brain isn't working correctly after breathing that stuff in.

Comment: I think I'd try pouring in a disinfectant -- laundry bleach, for example -- and hope that broke down enough of the gunk to make dipping it out tolerable. Otherwise, the only solutions I can think of involve cutting the pipes and repairing them later.

Comment: I threw some powdered ajax on top a few minutes ago. Hopefully the smell can be neutralized at least a little bit.

Comment: I'm not sure what's in Ajax, so I don't know whether you still have the option of bleach or if you'd risk creating poisonous gasses. I _think_ you'd be OK, but I'm not sure I'd want to bet my lungs on it; might be wise to contact the manufacturers before trying that.

Comment: It has bleach and a few other common ingredients used in scouring powders. I'll come back to it in the morning and maybe try the cup method again.

Comment: Make your relative that left it under there without telling anyone empty it?

Answer (score 3):

You should siphon the water out using a tube or flexible pipe.  I have included an article containing instructions on how to do this [here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/suction-water-small-pond-garden-hose-50394.html). You will have to adapt it to a much smaller scale, but the principle is the same.  If you just do a search for siphoning, maybe you will find a better/more applicable example. I just chose this article bc it wasn't about stealing gasoline. Let's not promote that slimy practice, shall we?

I had to do this once when the grease trap got clogged at work backed up into the sink. It was 11 pm and I had to get the "water" out of the sink so it wouldn't sit there all night and stink up the whole place. There was no WAY I was sticking my hand in there to scoop it out. Siphoning works. Give it a try.

Comment: Certainly should work if you have or get a suitable piece of tubing. Good thought.